# how do i send a custom message to a windows service?

Tags: windows, multithreading, delphi, service, message

I have implemented a windows xp service application that starts a couple of working threads.
From one of the threads i need to send custom messages back to the service.
How do i do that?

Comment: Your working threads are parts of your service application so it's unclear what you're trying to do. My impression is that you need to pass some data between threads, which can be done by simply keeping references to data structures and locking for thread safety. Depending on your intentions it might be easier for the main service thread to poll status of the worker threads. Could you provide more details?

Comment: I'll try to explain better. My service application creates two threads in its OnStart event. It also creates a list of objects (the objects have their own functions and properties). Now, one of the two threads polls the serial port for new data, and need to send this data (or timeout) to one of the objects from the objects list, but i need to do this without interrupting his execution. So when data are available on the serial port i want to post a message to the main service thread. This main service thread than can send the data to the object.

Comment: I understand that a possible solution would be to create a message-only window within the service class, but i don't exactly know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help. Here is how I solved the problem:

In the Service class definition:

```
  WHandle: HWND;
protected
  procedure HandleServiceMessage(var Msg: TMessage); virtual;
```

In the ServiceExecute method:

```
  WHandle := AllocateHWnd(HandleServiceMessage);
  MyThread := TMyThread.Create(true);
  MyThread.HndMain := WHandle;
  MyThread.Resume;
  while not Terminated do ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(True);
  DeallocateHWnd(WHandle);
end;
```

In ServiceStop method:

```
  MyThread.Terminate;
```

And the method for handling messages:

```
procedure TMessageService.HandleServiceMessage(var Msg : TMessage);
var
  Handled: Boolean;
begin
  Handled := True;
  if Msg.Msg = WM_MYMESSAGE then
    Beep
  else
    Handled := False;
  if Handled then
    Msg.Result := 0
  else
    Msg.Result := DefWindowProc(WHandle, Msg.Msg, Msg.WParam, Msg.LParam);
end;
```

In MyThread.Execute method:

```
  PostMessage(HndMain,WM_MYMESSAGE,0,0);
```

Its working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [OmniThreadLibrary](http://otl.17slon.com/) (read [this blog post](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2008/11/background-file-scanning-with.html) for an example).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with TOndrej that shared objects should be sufficient.

On the other hand you can use my IPC ([Cromis IPC](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/cromis-ipc/)) which works just fine inside services. It is easy to use, message oriented, so you don't need to know how named pipes work and very fast. The server part also uses a thread pool, so there is no waiting for something to be processed. You can use the fire and forget scenario.

Or if you think a little redesign is ok, you can try OmniThreadLibrary which has all the messaging already build in and is made for tasks like this.

**EDIT**:

Ok probably the cleanest way to go, without any redesing is to have a common object list which is protected by a critical section. The working thread is adding objects that need to be processed in the list. When and object is added the working thread signals an event. Then you have an object processing thread which is waiting with WaitForSingleObject for this event. As soon as something is added to the list the event is signaled and the processing thread just processes all the objects it finds in the list. Then it waits again. All you need to do is to protect the access to the common list.

Simplified the code would look like this:

WORKER THREAD

```
ObjectList.Add(MessageObject);
SetEvent(FEvent);
```

PROCESSING THREAD

```
while not Terminated do
begin
  WaitForSingleObjest(FEvent, INFINITE);
  // process all the objects
end;
```

Comment: I don't have time for redesign. The entire application works just fine except that part. I just need to run the internal objects functions from the main service thread, not from the working thread.

Comment: Then just use my IPC solution or implement what I suggested in my EDIT.

Comment: With this approach, I'd better create another thread who peek for the messages, and dispatches them to the right object.

Comment: I'll take a look at the IPC too

Answer (score 0):

Creating message-only window:

```
procedure TMyService.MessageQueueDispatch(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Dispatch(Message); //Delphi default dispatcher for TMyService
end;

procedure TMyService.SomeKindOfOnCreate;
begin
  MessageQueue := AllocateHWnd(MessageQueueDispatch);
end;
```

Destroying:

```
procedure TMyService.SomeKindOfDestroy;
begin
  CloseHandle(MessageQueue);
end;
```

Now you can handle messages like you would do with form messages:

```
TMyService = class(TService)
...
protected
  procedure HandleMyMessage(var msg: TMsg); message WM_MY_MESSAGE;
end;
```

Delphi Dispatch() handler will take care of calling the function.

Comment: AlloocateHWnd() is not thread-safe, and should not be called outside of the main thread.  TService runs in its own worker thread instead.